# MongoDB numeric index

Tags: database, mongodb

I was wondering if it's possible to create a numeric count index where the first document would be 1 and as new documents are inserted the count would increase. If possible are you also able to apply it to documents imported via mongoimport? I have created and index via `db.collection.createIndex( {index : 1} )` but it doesn't seem to be applying.

Comment: No, there are no auto-increment integer indexes in mongodb.

Comment: Is there anyway to go about making something to the same effect?

Comment: You can achieve something similar with `findAndModify`, but it will be far less reliable and convenient than native support.

Comment: What's the use case here? Maybe we can come up with an alternative approach?

Comment: Website pagination. Basically the index would allow me to find all the documents within a range to paginate instead of having to loop through the selection. So basically what I have is

`while <stuff>
try{
  has.next()
  total++
}
`
where every time I calculate the total I have to go through the loop due to pages only showing, say 100 documents at a time

Comment: @CMcCoy: you don't need integer sequence (and the index) for this. To get the next page, for example, `db.collection.find({_id: {$gt: last_seen_id}).limit(100)`  (where `last_seen_id` is the last id on the current page)

Comment: So the actual code is in java via the mongo java driver. I also have it grab from a specific range based on date. Such as 20171110 - 20171120. This would likely return 200k documents. Would limit still work in this case?

Comment: @CMcCoy: your page size is 200k? But yes, why wouldn't it work.

Comment: Sadly. The problem is I have to break that up into smaller increments like 100. So user loads the page and it returns 1-100/200k then they hit page 2 and it returns  101-200/200k and so on. Thus making the database do all the heavy lifting. However I don't know how to assign those 200k documents a value in my for loop. The collection currently has 2 million documents. Thus I thought the integer index would be a viable approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using ObjectId as your `_id` field. This has the benefit of being a good value for distributed systems, but also based on the date it was created. It also has a built-in index inside MongoDB.

Example using [Morphia](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/):

```
Date d = ...;
QueryImpl<MyClass> query = datastore.createQuery(MyClass);
query.field("_id").greaterThanOrEq(new ObjectId(d));
query.sort("_id");
query.limit(100);
List<MyClass> myDocs = query.asList();
```

This would fetch all documents created since date `d` in order of creation.

To load the next batch, change to:

```
query.field("_id").greaterThan(lastDoc.getId());
```

This will very efficiently load the next batch based on the ID of the last document from the previous batch.

Comment: Hey Nic, I am return all the dates fine. However what my problem is when I want to break up the documents I get back and just read a chunk of them I have to reloop through them until I get to the ones I want. I am unsure of how to assign all the documents a interger to just be able to use if else logic instead of looping and breaking.